# Deploying an EAR to JBOSS times out (org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.TimeoutException:)

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I am trying to deploy an ear file to JBOSS AS (defalut server). The application is the mavenised version of examples of SeamInAction book.

When I copy the file to $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy, I don't get any exception but the application doesn't respond, after some time trying to access the application from the browser gives following in the log...

While deploying with admin-console (http://localhost:8080/admin-console) I get following error messgae:

**PS: After this Jboss gets into unusable state. I cannot even access admin-console. I just have to kill it.**

ErrorMessage in admin-console:

> Failed to create Resource Open18.ear -
>   cause:
>   org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.TimeoutException:
>   Call to
>   [org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createResource()]
>   with args [[CreateResourceReport:
>   ResourceType=[ResourceType[id=0,
>   category=Service, name=Enterprise
>   Application (EAR), plugin=JBossAS5]],
>   ResourceKey=[null]]] timed out.
>   Invocation thread will be interrupted
>   at
>   org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ResourceComponentInvocationHandler.invokeInNewThreadWithLock(ResourceContainer.java:437)
>   at
>   org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ResourceComponentInvocationHandler.invoke(ResourceContainer.java:406)
>   at $Proxy266.createResource(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.CreateResourceRunner.call(CreateResourceRunner.java:113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Error Logs:

```
4:08:58,555 INFO  [TableMetadata] foreign keys: [fkaf42e01ba13c3380, fk_course_ref_facility]
14:08:58,555 INFO  [TableMetadata] indexes: [course_pkey]
14:08:58,645 INFO  [TableMetadata] table found: public.facility
14:08:58,645 INFO  [TableMetadata] columns: [zip, phone, state, type, uri, city, country, id, price_range, address, county, description, nam
e]
14:08:58,645 INFO  [TableMetadata] foreign keys: []
14:08:58,645 INFO  [TableMetadata] indexes: [facility_pkey]
14:08:58,705 INFO  [TableMetadata] table found: public.hole
14:08:58,705 INFO  [TableMetadata] columns: [id, m_par, l_handicap, name, l_par, number, course_id, m_handicap]
14:08:58,705 INFO  [TableMetadata] foreign keys: [fk_hole_ref_course, fk30f4c09c3f1200]
14:08:58,705 INFO  [TableMetadata] indexes: [hole_pkey, uniq_hole_number]
14:08:58,764 INFO  [TableMetadata] table found: public.tee
14:08:58,764 INFO  [TableMetadata] columns: [hole_id, distance, tee_set_id]
14:08:58,764 INFO  [TableMetadata] foreign keys: [fk1c014f8de7677, fk_tee_ref_hole, fk1c014c69de560, fk_tee_ref_tee_set]
14:08:58,764 INFO  [TableMetadata] indexes: [tee_pkey]
14:08:58,826 INFO  [TableMetadata] table found: public.tee_set
14:08:58,826 INFO  [TableMetadata] columns: [id, color, m_slope_rating, l_slope_rating, name, course_id, m_course_rating, l_course_rating, p
os]
14:08:58,826 INFO  [TableMetadata] foreign keys: [fk_tee_set_ref_course, fkaa6881b79c3f1200]
14:08:58,826 INFO  [TableMetadata] indexes: [tee_set_pkey, uniq_tee_set_pos, uniq_tee_set_color]
14:08:58,827 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] schema update complete
14:08:58,829 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.
naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
14:08:58,850 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/Open18
14:15:53,969 WARN  [DiscoveryComponentProxyFactory] The discovery component for resource type [ResourceType[id=0, category=Service, name=Connector, plugin=JBossAS5]] has been blacklisted
14:15:53,970 WARN  [InventoryManager] Failure during discovery for [Connector] Resources - failed after 300002 ms.
org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.TimeoutException: Call to [org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ConnectorDiscoveryComponent.discoverResources()] with args [[org.rhq.core.pluginapi.inventory.ResourceDiscoveryContext@96db1]] timed out. Invocation thread will be interrupted
        at org.rhq.core.pc.util.DiscoveryComponentProxyFactory$ResourceDiscoveryComponentInvocationHandler.invokeInNewThread(DiscoveryComponentProxyFactory.java:208)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.util.DiscoveryComponentProxyFactory$ResourceDiscoveryComponentInvocationHandler.invoke(DiscoveryComponentProxyFactory.java:181)
        at $Proxy249.discoverResources(Unknown Source)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.InventoryManager.invokeDiscoveryComponent(InventoryManager.java:272)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.InventoryManager.executeComponentDiscovery(InventoryManager.java:1697)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.discoverForResource(RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.java:218)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.discoverForResource(RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.java:234)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.runtimeDiscover(RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.java:134)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.call(RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.java:94)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.call(RuntimeDiscoveryExecutor.java:51)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:207)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
14:15:53,981 WARN  [NavigationContent] Unable to find node for deleted resource [Resource[id=-5, type=Connector, key=ajp://127.0.0.1:8009, name=ajp://127.0.0.1:8009, parent=JBoss Web]].
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was due to inclusion of the same library multiple times. This was fixed by adding exclusions in maven dependencies.